# Unable to upload translations file to prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am trying to upload ar.gzip file which contains arabic translations for prestashop using import section from Localization->Translations but whenever i upload the file i get this error
[image]

I read online that this error is caused because lang.php has an empty array element but in my case **mails/ar/lang.php** has no empty values

```
<?php

global $_LANGMAIL;
$_LANGMAIL = array();

$_LANGMAIL['Order confirmation'] = 'تأكيد طلب الشراء';
$_LANGMAIL['Log: You have a new alert from your shop'] = 'لديك تنبيه جديد من المتجر';
$_LANGMAIL['Fwd: Customer message'] = 'Fwd: رسالة العميل';
$_LANGMAIL['Your new password'] = 'كلمة المرور الجديدة';
$_LANGMAIL['New message regarding your order'] = 'رسالة جديد بخصوص طلب الشراء الخاص بك';
$_LANGMAIL['Process the payment of your order'] = 'معالجة الدفعة الخاصة بطلبك';
$_LANGMAIL['Your order return status has changed'] = 'لقد تم تغيير حالة اعادة طلب الشراء الخاص بك';
$_LANGMAIL['Welcome!'] = 'مرحباً';
$_LANGMAIL['Your message has been correctly sent #ct%1$s #tc%2$s'] = 'لقد تم ارسال رسالتك بنجاح #ct%1$s #tc%2$s';
$_LANGMAIL['Your message has been correctly sent'] = 'لقد تم ارسال رسالتك بنجاح';
$_LANGMAIL['Message from contact form'] = 'رسالة من نموذج الاتصال';
$_LANGMAIL['Message from a customer'] = 'رسالة من عميل';
$_LANGMAIL['Password query confirmation'] = 'تأكيد طلب كلمة المرور';
$_LANGMAIL['Newsletter voucher'] = 'قسيمة الرسائل البريدية';
$_LANGMAIL['Newsletter confirmation'] = 'تأكيد الاشتراك في النشرات الإخبارية';
$_LANGMAIL['Email verification'] = 'التحقق من البريد الإلكتروني';


return $_LANGMAIL;
```

Comment: Full path of file  ?

Answer (score 0):

Content should be like this :

```
$_LANG['address_57d056ed0984166336b7879c2af3657f'] = 'City';
```

Here `address` is the file name in which the text `City` is used and `57d056ed0984166336b7879c2af3657f` is the md5 of 'City' and you can write text on RHS based on your language.

Also file name should be LANGUAGE_ISO_CODE.php like ar.php for Arabic.